# How to add data in the below format?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck to add data in JS. I am not sure whether this could be done or not. I have tried but I failed to do so.

The below data needs to send to prepare in the API format.

```
0: { id2: 79, id3: 18}
1: { id2: 79, id3: 19}
2: { id2: 80, id3: 30}
```

I have to send the data to api in the below format.

For example: in APi format demands: id2 becomes key and id3 is value will be added to the same key and if there is new id2 then new key becomes and value will be added

```
"data1":{
"79":[18,19],
"80": [30],
}
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear about what you are trying to do, achieve and what you have tried. I see some sample code which is kinda unreadable. What is newdata1? Why it gets iterated too? `var item = {};` unused declared variable. `newdata1[i]=newdata1[frontendata[i].id2]=[frontendata[i].id3]` . Why are 2 equals here, you need to give further details on your question and what you've tried

Comment: Sorry about that. i have made changes in the explanation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
let data = [  { id2: 79, id3: 18},  { id2: 79, id3: 19},  { id2: 80, id3: 30}];

let data1 = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  if (!acc[current.id2]) {
    acc[current.id2] = []
  }
  acc[current.id2].push(current.id3)
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(data1)
```

Comment: wow, thank you. I did not know reduce function could do this too. amazing. Thank you so much

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Laravel Liwevire Question

Comment: @DSDmark I don't know why everybody acts as a moderator here. I simply gave him a solution while he had -2 votes. There are several other questions on how reduce works and how to work with objects and arrays, and that obviously wasn't his question, his question was "How do I solve this?" and I gave him my approach. The code is obviously self explanatory, all he has to do is take a look at how reduce works, which he should have done and tried before even coming to ask for help.

Comment: I agree @DSDmark, that could force me to think for a solution. But this solution also made me reading the whole mdn about reduce function. I am practicing and now I can relate reduce function with my real practical problem which is making it understanding too much better. Yes I did not read reduce function in detail. But thank you Laravel Liwevire Question 

But for others, here is the page which people can read it too. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#grouping_objects_by_a_property